# How to edit spree search query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I want to edit spree search query as it is not returning optimized results. for example if i search for a product name "the product" it searches for all products with the name "the" or the name "product" or description "the" or "product" as a result of which the product with exactly the name "the product" is shown some where in the middle not at the top. here is the query

```
SELECT  DISTINCT "spree_products"."id", spree_products_taxons.position AS alias_0 FROM "spree_products" INNER JOIN "spree_variants" ON "spree_variants"."product_id" = "spree_products"."id" AND "spree_variants"."is_master" = 't' AND "spree_variants"."deleted_at" IS NULL INNER JOIN "spree_prices" ON "spree_prices"."variant_id" = "spree_variants"."id" AND "spree_prices"."deleted_at" IS NULL LEFT OUTER JOIN "spree_products_taxons" ON "spree_products_taxons"."product_id" = "spree_products"."id" WHERE "spree_products"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ("spree_products".deleted_at IS NULL or "spree_products".deleted_at >= '2015-09-12 17:02:36.804128') AND ("spree_products".available_on <= '2015-09-12 17:02:36.804764') AND "spree_products_taxons"."taxon_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15) AND (("spree_products"."name" ILIKE '%the%' OR "spree_products"."name" ILIKE '%product%') OR ("spree_products"."description" ILIKE '%the%' OR "spree_products"."description" ILIKE '%product%')) AND (spree_prices.amount IS NOT NULL) AND "spree_prices"."currency" = 'PKR'  ORDER BY spree_products_taxons.position ASC, asc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

I need to optimize this so that the most related product is shown at the top and i cannot find the exact file or class where this query is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Spree uses [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) to create these queries. You won't find them directly coded. the code would probably look something like `Spree::Product.ransack(name_cont: "query")`